# Can I set attribute on a parent node after writing children with XmlWriter

Tags: xml, xmlwriter

I am writing rows from a one-directional data reader to xml. Xml structure is like

```
<rows Count="10"><row/>..<row/></rows>
```

I do not know the row count upfront. What is the best a way to write count attribute in this scenario? Currently I write all rows, load the string in XmlDocument and generate the attribute. It does work, but what if I had a lot of rows?

Comment: The best idea would be to not use an `XmlWriter`. Write the data directly into the XmlDocument, and when you're done, add the Count attribute.

Comment: Not sure how I can write directly to XmlDocument. As far as I know, XmlWriter writes to a stream.

Comment: I see..
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())

Comment: Good find. It took me _years_ to find that technique. Note that it works with _any_ class that implements `IXPathNavigable`.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.